# How to extract certain text inside a file using findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm trying to scan a text file, and wanted to get the version only

I've tried running this

```
>for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=, " %i  in (`findstr /l "version" "C:\Test\myfiles\package.text"`) do echo %i
```

however it's returning an entry twice

```
echo "4.2.20"
"4.2.20"
```

The text file has this format

```
 "version":  "4.2.20",
```

how to use `findstr` to return only the exact version in this format `4.2.20`

Thank you!

Comment: it does *not* display anything twice. What you see, is a) command repetition (it shows the command to be executed next) and b) the output. You can suppress command repetition with a `@`:  `... do @echo %i` (or to be complete: `@for ...... do @echo %i`)

Comment: to remove surrounding quotes: `@echo %~i`

Comment: hi @Stephan , is there a way to return on the following format 4.220 (remove the last decimal/period?). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Q:`is there a way to return on the following format 4.220 (remove the last decimal/period?)`

A: there is. Split the version string (handle it like a filename, so the first part (`%%~ni, "Filename"`) gets anything before the last dot and the second part (`%%~xi`, "extension" gets the last dot and everything after). Then simply remove the dot from the "extension" and merge the two substrings:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=, " %%i  in (`findstr /l "version" "C:\Test\myfiles\package.text"`) do (
  set "major=%%~ni"
  set "minor=%%~xi"
)

set "version=%major%%minor:.=%"
echo method 1: %version%

set "version=%major%%minor:~1%"
echo method 2: %version%
```

It *is* possible to do it in a single command line, but as you need delayed expansion, this gets ugly, hard to read and maintain. Not worth the effort, except you have a special requirement for that, IMHO. So (because you also tagged `batch-file`) I stuck to that.