# Remove last decimal/period on echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have the following batch file. It scans a json file to retrieve the version.

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=, " %%i  in (`findstr /l "version" "C:\test\test\package.json"`) do @set str=%%~i
@set str=%str:.=%
@echo.%str%
```

It's returning correctly like the version 4.2.20 from my json file., and remove the periods as well.

my questions however, is there a way to remove the last period/decimal only?

Currently it's returning like this
if the version is 4.2.20 = it returns 4220
if the version is 3.4.1 = it returns 341.

I want it to return to this only 4.220 or 3.41
Thank You!

Comment: If there are never more than two dots, you could use this: `for /F "tokens=1-2* delims=." %%A in ("%str%") do echo(%%A.%%B%%C`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split variable **%STR%** in two parts. The usual way is **FOR**-parser.
Use second **FOR**-cycle. For correct variable processing enable *[Delayed environment variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)* in cycle.

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=, " %%i  in (`findstr /l "version" "C:\test\test\package.json"`) do @set str=%%~i
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=. " %%i  in ('%str%') do (
set str=%%j
set str=!str:.=!
set str=%%i.!str!
@echo.!str!
)
@endlocal
```

Comment: technically this doesn't "remove the last dot only", but `keep the first dot only` (to the same result, *if* there are exactly two dots). See my answer [here[(https://stackoverflow.com/a/68078061/2152082)